Py4JJavaError when using apache iceberg
i can't create a table when using apache iceberg, please help me
Py4JJavaError
Cell In[2], line 25
     22 print("Spark Running")
     24 ## Run a Query to create a table
---> 25 spark.sql("CREATE TABLE iceberg.table1 (name string) USING iceberg;")


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
